# UIBarButtonItem image and color

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I need to add a UIBarButtonItem programmatically to the navigation bar of a viewController.

I am using the following code to do it, but it only shows the button text, and I want to show the system default rewind button and change its default color:

```
UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(backButton:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

The button action is correct. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this? :-)

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind target:self action:selector(backButton:)];
backButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Best,
Sascha

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:` for system items. To change the color of the item, set the `tintColor` of the navigation bar to the color you need.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use an item type as a style, which you can't do, they are different enum types.

You should consider creating a custom image to use on your bar button. Or, creating a view which contains a label and an image and setting that as the custom view of the bar button.